Computing Sum of Distinct Rows
I'm working in Power Query, and have the following table:



Year
Type
Value




2022
A
13


2022
B
5


2023
A
11


2023
B
36


2024
A
9


2024
B
22



I'd like to add the values of type A and type B together, to produce the following table:



Year
Value A + Value B




2022
18


2023
47


2024
31



Is this possible in Power Query? I'd prefer not to do this "manually" using cell-specific formulas in Excel. The biggest issue I run into is not being able to reference other rows based on a specific cell value.
Bonus points if you know how to do this, replacing simple summation with a more complicated function.
My guess
I could figure out how to do it if I were able to manipulate the first table into something that looks like



Year
Value A
Value B




2022
13
5


2023
11
36


2024
9
22



This feels close to a pivot, but not quite.

It is a simple Table.Group operation
M Code from the Advanced Editor
let

//change next line to reflect your actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],


    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Type", type text}, {"Value", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Year"}, {
        {"Sum", each List.Sum([Value]), type nullable number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"

In the User Interface, you would

navigate to Home=>Transform=>GroupBy
Then fill out the dialog as shown below


By the way, your guess table is, in Power Query, a simple Pivot
Also, in Excel, if you have the latest 365 version, you can reproduce the output using a Table with structured references, so you do not have to deal with varying cell references. For example: =GROUPBY(your_table[[#All],[Year]],your_table[[#All],[Value]],SUM,3,0) will produce the same output as Power Query, and will autoupdate when you change your original data
Output from above Excel formula


Ah, you're right! Is there a way to do this with a more complicated function than Sum? If, say, I wanted to do [Value A]*[Value A]*sin([Value B]) or something silly like that.

@GoodAnalysis Yes, there is a way, and you should post a new question for what you want. It seems as if you have asked about an X-Y Problem. I suggest that in your next post, you ask about your actual problem.

I asked for both -- my "actual problem" along with a question for my own understanding. Thanks for the inviting and welcoming tone.

@GoodAnalysis You are welcome. And as I mentioned in my answer, your other question about your other table can be solved with the pivot operation

if you want to do the complicated calculation,you can pivot the table first
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjIwMlLSUXIEYkNjpVgduIgTEJvCBIxhSgyRRUBKjM1gIiZQNZbIAiAlQONiYwE=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Year = _t, Type = _t, Value = _t]),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Source, List.Distinct(Source[Type]), "Type", "Value")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"


then value A and B will in the same row and that will be easier for you to do the further calculation.
